# Prove that $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $(a,\infty)$ contains all the intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove that if a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ contains intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$, then it contains all the intervals.

Proof:

Let $\mathscr{B}$ to denote the $\sigma$-algebra defined above. We have that since $(a,\infty) \in \mathscr{B}$, then since it contains the complement, we have that it also contains the intervals of the form $(-\infty,b]$, i.e. $$(-\infty,b] \in \mathscr{B}$$
In particular, we have that $(a,b) \in \mathscr{B}$. It's enough to prove that:
$$[b, \infty) \in \mathscr{B}$$
$$[a,b] \in \mathscr{B}$$
$$[a,b) \in \mathscr{B}$$
$$(a,b) \in \mathscr{B}$$
This is clear, since: 
$$[b, \infty) = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} (b-\frac{1}{n}, \infty)$$
$$[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})$$
$$[a,b) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a,b+\frac{1}{n})$$
$$(a,b) = \mathscr{B} \backslash [(-\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty)]$$
Is this proof correct?

Comment: You say in particular that $(a, b) \in \mathscr R$, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @JohnMa   correct me if I am wrong, I can write: $(a,b) = \mathscr{B} \backslash [(-\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty)]$.

Comment: Technically you haven't shown $[b, \infty) \in \mathscr R$ yet.

Comment: then I need to prove $[b, \infty) \in \mathscr R$ and I'm done?

Comment: Yes, the remaining of your works are correct.

Comment: $[b, \infty) = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} (b-\frac{1}{n}, \infty)$.

Comment: what about $(-\infty,b)$?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If this is Problem 11 in Section 2.3 of _Real Analysis_ by Royden and Fitzpatrick, it remains to show that all intervals are of the forms you listed. The authors leave that proof as a reader exercise on page 10 of the text.

Comment: @user0 I'm reading this late, hence I apologize. I will check page 10 of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A new organized answer is required.

$\newcommand{\b}{\mathscr B}$Ok, I will give it.

What is the structure of an interval? It is one of the following : $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b],[a,b]$, where one of $a,b$ could be $\pm \infty$.

Let us start with $(a,\infty) \in \b$ for all $a \color{blue}{(1)}$.

Without complementation, note that $[a,\infty) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a-\frac 1n,\infty\right)$, so $[a,\infty) \in \b$ for all $a\color{blue}{(2)}$.

Now, the complements of $\color{blue}{(1)}$ give $(-\infty,b] \in \b$ for all $b\color{blue}{(3)}$.

The complements of $\color{blue}{(2)}$ give $(-\infty,b) \in \b$ for all $b\color{blue}{(4)}$.

Thus, one sees that all cases where one endpoint is infinite is covered. This can be used to systematically process the rest of the intervals.

---

Now,

- $(a,b) = \mathbb R \setminus ((-\infty,a] \cup [b,\infty))$.
- $[a,b) = \mathbb R \setminus ((-\infty,a) \cup [b,\infty)$.
- $(a,b] = \mathbb R \setminus ((-\infty,a] \cup (b,\infty))$.
- $[a,b] = \mathbb R \setminus ((-\infty,a) \cup (b,\infty))$.

Which shows that each of these intervals, for arbitrary $a \leq b \in \mathbb R$ belong to $\b$.